# Erro em tempo de execução "5852"

Tags: vba, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Utilizei esse código para gerar uma mala direta e separar os arquivos.

Porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> Erro em tempo de execução "5852"
> O Objeto solicitado não está disponível.

Uso o office 365

---

```
Sub SalvarComoDOCIndividual()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim registro As Integer
    Dim nomeArquivo As String

    'Define o primeiro registro da mala direta
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

    'Contador de registros
    a = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount

    'Salva todos os registros
    For registro = 1 To a
        'Atribui o valor de cada registro da coluna nome para a variável nomeArquivo que dará nome ao novo arquivo. Caso queira outro nome, basta colocar o nome da coluna desejada
        nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("ALUNO").Value
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
            "C:\Users\usuario\arquivos\" & nomeArquivo & ".docx", FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
        :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
        :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Next registro
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: Faltou explicar em que linha o erro ocorre.

Answer (score -2):

Esse erro normalmente aparece quando objeto MailMerge não existe e quando você está tentando executar a mala direta.

Experimente primeiro, criar uma mala direta em seu documento do Word.

Basta usar o assistente e esse objeto será preenchido automaticamente e depois execute o código